# How can I send 2 or more variables fron JavaScript to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my JavaScript code.

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  var warnings = document.getElementById('warnings_panel');
  warnings.innerHTML = '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  showSteps(response);
  // Display the distance:
  distantakm = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
  timph = parseInt(distantakm / 60); 
  timpm = parseInt((distantakm / 60 - timph) * 60);
  document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = "Distanta este de " + distantakm + " metri";
  document.getElementByName('timpul').innerHTML = "Timpul este" + timpm + " minute";
}
```

I want to send these 3 variables: `timph`, `timpm` and `distantakm` to an HTML fieldset. I tried this version, but it doesn't work. Also, I tried using jQuery, but I don't know exactly how to use it. Please offer me a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I apologize, but I do not know what you mean because I'm a beginner. In HTML, i have this : <text type="text" id = "distance"><br>
 <text type="text" id="timpul"><br>

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementByName('timpul')` - this is wrong.
First of all there is no such method but there is a [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName).

For this your *HTML*

```
<input type="text" id="distance"> <br>
<input type="text" id="timpul"> <br>
```

(by the way it should be tag `input` or `textarea` but not a tag `text` as you wrote in your comment)

you should use the method [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and assign a value of `value` attribute for that inputs:

```
document.getElementById('distance').value = "Distanta este de " + distantakm + " metri";
document.getElementById('timpul').value = "Timpul este" + timpm + " minute";
```